# Running and scheduling processing jobs in QGIS 3?

Tags: python, qgis-3, tasks, scheduler

Basically I want to write a script that would run on a daily basis on QGIS 3. This tutorial seems to have exactly what I want but the tutorial only works for QGIS 2.

[QGIS Tutorials and Tips | Running and Scheduling QGIS Processing Jobs](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html)

How can I make the same thing in QGIS 3?

Comment: Scripting with processing has changed, standalone scripts have changed, pyqis api and Python have changed. Where do you want to start?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at that post and It seems very customizable but is quite complex too and It need some windows tools (to execute a batch file through time etc). This is why I propose you other approach just using the QGIS console and a python script.

[Here you have a complete script with an scheduled proces](https://github.com/cesarkero/QGIS_scripts/blob/master/QGIS_3.8_console/BufferDaily.py). This does a buffer each 10 seconds between an starting time and ending time. In case you need other process just substitute that part...

Here is a quide of the process.

- Parameters: "layer" is the shp or gpkg for the buffer. "t0" and "t1" are the start and end of the process using the structure AAAAMMDD_HHmmss. "s" is the time passed between processes in seconds. "bufferdist" and "bufferdiss" are parameters of the buffer runalg. "outdir" is the folder where all the outputs are going to be saved.
- Function gpkg4QGIS: this have been writen to create the output string that QGIS needs in order to export to gkpg. This sring of the output name is quite complex to parametrized, so dont't worry. The function does for you. You just need to pass the output folder and the filename (which is done also for you iteratively using the processing time).
- Settings for schedule: just do some functions over you parameters in order to convert those initial strings to datetimes and "waiting" time.
- PROCESS: this is the part that may be scares you but don't worry, is not that complex. In case you dont want to keep reading just change the processing algorith of QGIS in the "processing.run("native:buffer..." part. 
  In case you want to know something else keep reading [...]
- [...] The process runs using "threading.Timer" functions that allows you to "stop" the process while QGIS is waiting for the next iteration. You can rewrite this part with clean "whiles" but is gonna cost you this lack of functionality. So, the first part just waits for the starting time. The second part process and exports the buffer and updates the t0 using the "s" parameter. When the time comes, it works again. The exported files have the AAAAMMDD_HHmmss of the process so you can easily sort files.

IMPORTANT THING 1: In case something goes wrong just execute `x.cancel()` and `y.cancel()` to stop all processes.

I recomend not using that QGIS window to work during the execution. Open a new one. Don't close that QGIS interface during execution.

Here is the screenshot of the console:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import qgis, qgis.core, glob, time, sys, threading, os
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from PyQt5 import Qt
import time, threading

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# parameters as objects for processing
layer = '/home/user/input/layer.gpkg' 
t0 = '20200207_105300' #starting time
t1 = '20200207_105400' #ending time
s = 10
bufferdist = 50
bufferdiss = True
outdir = '/home/user/output'

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# functions
def gpkg4QGIS (outputdir, layername):
    '''This function gets a path and a layer name and creates an string that works as gpkg output in QGIS
    processing'''
    pn = os.path.realpath(outputdir + '/' + layername + '.gpkg')
    p = f"'{pn}'"
    f = f'"{layername}"'
    return (f'ogr:dbname={p} table={f} (geom) sql=')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# settings for schedule
t0 = datetime.strptime(t0, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
t1 = datetime.strptime(t1, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
f = timedelta(seconds=s)
ct = datetime.now()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROCESS
if datetime.now() > t1:
    print ("Cancel all for bad schedule")
    x.cancel()
    y.cancel()

# elif vlayer.isValid():
#     print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    x = None

    def wait4t0():
        global x
        global t0

        x = threading.Timer(s, wait4t0)
        x.start()
        print('Waiting for t0')

        while datetime.now() > t0:
            x.cancel()

    wait4t0()

    y = None

    def work2t1():
        global y
        global t0

        y = threading.Timer(s, work2t1)
        y.start()

        if datetime.now() > t1:
            y.cancel()

        if datetime.now() > t0:
            # Process
            # 1 set filename
            fname = str(t0)
            for i in ['-',':']:
                fname = fname.replace(i, '')
            fname.replace(" ","_")

            # 2 buffer
            print("Process time - filename:" + str(datetime.now()) + ' - ' + fname)
            inputlayer = os.path.abspath(layer)
            outputlayer = gpkg4QGIS(outdir,fname)
            processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'INPUT': layer,
                'DISTANCE': bufferdist, 'SEGMENTS': 20, 'END_CAP_STYLE': 0, 'JOIN_STYLE': 0, 'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'DISSOLVE': bufferdiss,
                'OUTPUT': outputlayer})

            # update t0
            t0 = t0+f

        while t0 > t1:
            y.cancel()

    work2t1()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Tools to stop process before t1
# x.cancel()
# y.cancel()
```

PD: This was created in QGIS 3.10