# Setup a QGIS model to run on an Ubuntu server automatically

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql-server, qgis-modeler

I made a QGIS model tool that pulls a copy of two datasets from a MSSQL db and runs several sets of geoprocessing tasks and outputs a single resulting dataset to a pgSQL db.

This process runs successfully (very slowly) on my local machine. I want to have this tool run automatically on an Ubuntu server machine I have setup once a week (The same one that hosts the pgSQL db, among other things). How would you go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: Related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336163/running-and-scheduling-processing-jobs-in-qgis-3). The linked tutorial is interesting too